# Is it possible to print a form cs file from another form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

form2 holds a rdlc preview which i want to print from form2 and not rldc
how would  i do that fron btnPrint_click method?

searched online but only shows how to print from same forms file.

form1

> ```
>  private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
>         localReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\form2.cs";//gives an error
>         localReport.PrintToPrinter();
>         localReport.Refresh();
>     }
> ```

Comment: Just to confirm: you know this would use the server's printers, right?

Comment: Yes my objective is to print the form to a pdf file for further use. @DiplomacyNotWar

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar You got any ideas?